# Why does the romanization Mahjong have a final H after ma?

Tags: romanization

What romanization system of what language or dialect is this from?
I've seen no other romanization of Mandarin or other Chinese languages or dialects use a final H.

Or may it be just common english-speaking use to avoid being pronounced may-jong?

Comment: Mahjong spread to West way before Pinyin, so I think your guess is correct. It's a non-ambiguous English spelling to reproduce the sound.

Comment: Mahjong spread to the west slightly before Wade Giles did, and decades before Hanyu Pinyin was created.

Comment: I think only an English\* etymologist could possibly have an answer. *: note that "Mahjong" is actually an English word, not Chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Mahjong In The West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahjong#Mahjong_in_the_West)

I think it is just a translation problem.

In the old times, romanisation in Chinese Language like [Cantonese Romanisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyutping) is not really common, like in this case, Mahjong might be translated from the Wu Dialect or Northern Chinese Language, I'm not sure about that.

You might also refer to this [The Mahjong Origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176842/what-is-the-story-behind-the-word-mahjong)

I hope I did answer your question. :)

Answer (score -1):

It's because the English spelling is based on an old Chinese romanization system called 'Wade-Giles' ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade–Giles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade%E2%80%93Giles)) (I think).

Comment: Where in the article speaks about ah? I can only find eh and ih.

Comment: This is not Wade Giles.

Comment: Hmm... maybe not. Maybe it's not a standard romanization system and just arbitrarily chosen spelling.

Answer (score -1):

It's a perfectly normal way of transcribing the long "aahhh" sound into English. In this case it tells us that the game is not mayjong, nor muhjong.

No doctor ever asked you to "Say a."  It's always "Say `Ah'."

Comment: I have never seen a doctor write down what you're supposed to say to open your mouth.